# Join DataTables to get new DataTable via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've a datatable named which contains data with a column of ID, firstname, lastname. Another datatable contains columns of code, `userID1`, `userID2`, `userID3`, work.

Now i want a new datatable which should contain the column of both the datatable with proper data.

New datatable should contain data as: `ID`, `userfullname1`, `userfullname2`, `userfullname3`, work.

Here we get the value of `userfullname1` by firstname, lastname of datatable1 & `userID1` of `datatable2`. Similarly we  get the value of `userfullname2` by firstname, lastname of **`datatable1`** & `userID2` of **`datatable2`** & so on.

The value of ID in **`Datatable1`** is same as `userID1`, `userID2`, `userID3` in **`Datatable2`**.

Finally, i want to obtain a new datatable with code, userfullname1, userfullname2, userfullname3, work. But users IDs are in datatable1. So, i want to bind the names of Datatable1 to the all 3 userids of Datatable2 via their IDs whichare present in both the tables.

Datatable1 :

```
iD  name
1    b
2    d
3    f
4    s
```

....

Datatable2 :

```
   Code        userid1    userid2      userid3  work
    1f           1           3           6       gg
    2g           1           4           7       gg
    3b           3           4           7       gg
    4v           4           3           8       gg
```

New Datatable :

```
Code    username1   username2   username3  work
1f           a           b           c       gg
2g           d           f           r       gg
3b           c           h           g       gg
4v           d           s           h       gg
```

How can i join & get the new datatable ?

Comment: But the tables that you are showing now are different than what you have mentioned in the question, aren't  they? For example: _"userID1, userID2, userID3 in Datatable2"_ or _"ID, firstname, lastname in Datatable1"_ It's also unclear how the tables are linked, it seems to be wrong what you've mentioned here: _"value of ID in Datatable1 is same as userID1, userID2, userID3 in Datatable2"_

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a table with User Ids and you want to join your profile table to get those names.  You can do this with sub-queries like:

```
var myTable = UserIds.Select(u => new
{
    User1FullName = u.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == u.userId1).Select(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName),
    User2FullName = u.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == u.userId2).Select(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName)
    // etc...
});
```

You can do it with joins like:

```
var myTable = (from u in UserIds
               join p1 in UserProfiles on u.UserId1 equals p1.UserId
               join p2 in UserProfiles on u.UserId2 equals p2.UserId
               // etc...
               select new
               {
                   User1FullName = p1.FirstName + " " + p1.LastName,
                   User2FullName = p2.FirstName + " " + p2.LastName,
                   // etc...
               });
```

Comment: I didnt understands what is `UserIds` in your code. Is this the datarow from datatable2? Do i need to put the linq syntax in loop to get all the 3 names from each row from datatable1?

Comment: My assumption was that you have two tables, one that contains the names, and another table which contains only user IDs and some other data.  In order to get the names based on the user IDs, I am showing you how to do a sub-query and a join.  No loop is required.  Simply put a breakpoint in your code to see the results of the query variable `myTable`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to achieve what you want:

```
DataTable tblResult = new DataTable();
tblResult.Columns.Add("ID"); 
tblResult.Columns.Add("userfullname1"); 
tblResult.Columns.Add("userfullname2"); 
tblResult.Columns.Add("userfullname3"); 
tblResult.Columns.Add("Work");

var query = from r1 in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
            from r2 in datatable2.AsEnumerable()
            let id = r1.Field<int>("ID")
            let userID1 = r2.Field<int>("userID1")
            let userID2 = r2.Field<int>("userID2")
            let userID3 = r2.Field<int>("userID3")
            where id == userID1 && id == userID2 && id == userID3
            select new { r1, r2, id, userID1, userID2, userID3 };
foreach (var x in query)
{
    DataRow row = tblResult.Rows.Add();
    string firstName = x.r1.Field<string>("firstname");
    string lastName = x.r1.Field<string>("lastname");
    string userfullname1 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, lastName, x.userID1);
    string userfullname2 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, lastName, x.userID2);
    string userfullname3 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, lastName, x.userID3);
    row.SetField("ID", x.id);
    row.SetField("userfullname1", userfullname1);
    row.SetField("userfullname2", userfullname2);
    row.SetField("userfullname3", userfullname3);
    row.SetField("Work", x.r2.Field<string>("Work"));
}
```

Comment: No result occured `Enumeration yielded no results` in the variable query. I have the userIDs i.e. userid1, userid2, userid3 in the datatable2 but i want to show the name of the users, so there is a different datatable which contains both the userids with their fullname. Now i want to get the new datatable with all 3 usersfullnames instead of userIDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want your resulting table to have name and id, you should do it like this:

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));


var result = from datatable1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join datatable2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
             on datatable1.Field<string>("ID") equals datatable2.Field<string>("userID")

             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                datatable1.Field<string>("ID"),               
        string.Format("{0} {1}" ,datatable1.Field<string>("fname") ,datatable1.Field<string>("lname")),

              }, false);
result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: According to your code, it will match only first userID in the datatable2 but i want to get the names of all the 3 usersIDs of Datatable2 from Datatable1.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_28284094.html.

Comment: Loading the content from your tables `.AsEnumerable()` will enumerate your results thus loading all of their contents into memory.  So, this could hinder performance if your tables are too large.