# Join several DataTables with DataRelations into a new DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, xml, join, dataset

I have a Dataset with several tables (number of tables may vary, same as table names and structure). I'd like to get a new table with the join of pre-existing tables, joining both columns and rows.

The Dataset is loaded from an XML file with:

```
DataSet dsXML = new DataSet();
dsXML.ReadXml(strXMLPath);
```

XML files are created with Oracle Reports 6i, and we have several reports, with different structures, so XML file might be parsed to one o many tables.  If you open XML file with Microsoft Excel, it's data is "magically" joined into one table, and I'd like to achieve the same result automatically, without user doing anything and without having to have installed Office.

I've managed to iterate over Dataset's DataRelations and collect all of the columns I'm interested in (all columns except joined columns that are duplicated in parent and child tables, and I'm getting only one of them):

```
bool blnContinue = true;
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
List<DataColumn> allColumns = new List<DataColumn>();
while (blnContinue)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        if (table.ParentRelations != null 
            && table.ParentRelations.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!table.ParentRelations[0].ChildColumns.Contains(col))
                allColumns.Add(col);
        }
        else
        {
            allColumns.Add(col);
        }
    }
    if (table.ChildRelations != null && table.ChildRelations.Count > 0)
        table = table.ChildRelations[0].ChildTable;
    else blnContinue = false;
}
```

As columns are tightly bound to their tables, I'd have to iterate over `allColumns` object to create new columns with the same name (all columns are created with string datatype). And after new columns are created, iterate again over Dataset and Datarelations to have all of the data.

I've tried with

```
var tablesJoined = from t1 in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                   join t2 in ds.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>() on t1["key_column"] equals t2["key_column"]
                   select new { t1, t2 };
```

And read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773530/join-datatables-to-get-new-datatable-via-linq). But I don't know Linq enough and don't know how to dinamically create the sentence so it can be used with any number of tables. Also "key_column" may vary so I have to set it dinamically, depending on the tables I have.

An example of how could be XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 6.0.8.11.3 -->
<SOME_ROOT_LABEL>
  <BEGIN_LIST_LABEL>
    <RECORD_LABEL>
      <PROPERTY_LABEL1>XXX</PROPERTY_LABEL1>
      <PROPERTY_LABEL2>YYY</PROPERTY_LABEL2>
      <PROPERTY_LABEL3>ZZZ</PROPERTY_LABEL3>
        ...
    </RECORD_LABEL>
    ...
    <RECORD_LABEL>
        ...
    </RECORD_LABEL>
  </BEGIN_LIST_LABEL>
  <SOME_OTHER_LABEL> whatever </SOME_OTHER_LABEL>
</SOME_ROOT_LABEL>
```

After having all of the data into only one DataTable, I want to create a ".xlsx" file (maybe using Epplus).

Is there a better way to achieve this (join N DataTables with DataRelations into only one).

Comment: With complicated xml files the DataSet ReadXml() method fragments the data into tables that CANNOT be recombined.  It is better to use Xml Linq to custom parse the xml files into a single table.  I have done this lots of times.

Comment: What do you mean with "CANNOT be recombined"? ReadXML() creates DataTables with DataRelatios, so navigation between tables is possible. Also, XML schema is different between files, when parsing with ReadXML() there can be 2, 3 or any number of tables. I'll sutdy better this solution.

Comment: The first level tag is the DataSet name.  Second level Tags are the DataTable names. Third Level tags are the column names.  Fourth Level tags are the row data.  Once you have more than 4 layers of tags the Data Library fragments the data into more tables that can't be used.

Comment: @jdweng that's not the way ReadXML is creating Dataset. Root tag is the name of the first table. First label in the second level is the name of the second table. First label in the third level is the name of the third table. Number of levels is only known at runtime, when Dataset.readXML() is invoked.

Comment: Wrong.   Don't get the DataTable ReadXml method and DataSet ReadXml mixed up.  The DataSet has an extra level of tags.